# Various groups and individuals and their relation to a specific tribe

Tags: sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, ashkenazi, yosef, shevatim-12-tribes, yehuda

1.Is there anyone who attributes the tribe/kingdom of Yehudah to Sefardim, and the tribe/kingdom of Yosef to Ashkenazim (at least in the spiritual sense), as per [Ovadiah 1:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Obadiah.1.20?lang=bi&with=all)?

2. are there any pairs of individuals or sects who were said to each represent the spiritual path of one of these two tribes/kingdoms?
3. Which individuals or groups from after the exile of the ten tribes  are said to be from one of the ten tribes?

Comment: The chasam sofer says the different nuschaot of tefila are from the different tribes. OC 15, 16, 197.

Comment: There's the legend of some Ethiopian Jews being from discontented Dan-ites who gave up and left Israel in the First Temple era...

Comment: And a group of Jews in India who claimed to be from Menashe. But the Ashkenaz/Sefard split came much, much later; it would be folly to try and trace that to the two First Temple kingdoms. It sure sounds like the vast majority of folks in today's identified Jewish mainstream are descendants of those in the South Kingdom.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following Jewish/Israelite groups have a tradition for specific tribal ancestry:

Ethiopians - [Tribe of Dan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Israel#Tribe_of_Dan)

Jews in India - Tribe of Menashe

Bukharian Jews - [Tribes of Naphtali and Issachar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bukharan_Jews#History)

Samaritans - [Descendants of Joseph, Menashe, and Levi](https://www.the-samaritans.net/)